# Using an xcode workspace to have multiple projects with dependencies

Tags: xcode4.3, workspace

I am trying to use a workspace with two projects in the workspace, and access the ViewControllers in one project in the other. I think a screenshot best depicts what is happening. I am importing `DirectoryViewController.h` into the `AppDelegate.h` file of the Test project, and the `DirectoryViewController` comes from the AssociationLibrary. When I started typing `DirectoryViewController` for the import, auto-complete gave me the option for `DirectoryViewController`, but then I got the **file not found** warning. Anyone have experience with this?

[image]